# Ubuntu won't start (12.10 with Windows 8 dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, windows-8

I updated my PC to Windows 8 and after that installed Ubuntu 12.10. I have 128 GB SSD now partitioned to 36 GB for Ubuntu and rest for Windows 8. Everything worked well, I installed few programs and downloaded updates for the Ubuntu. Ubuntu asked me to restart in order to updates to work. After that restart the trouble began. Now I can only log in to Ubuntu and all it shows after that, is the background image. Windows works correctly, everything shows up in the grub.

I presume that something went wrong with updates. Is there anything I can do for it or should I just install the whole thing again?

Cheers!

Comment: This sounds like a graphics card problem. Which graphics card do you have? Have you installed "Additional Drivers" for the card? Please edit the question with more information.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 ahows anything?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install "Windows 8" first before installing "Ubuntu" . .
because the major bootloader is in the "windows 8" and then install "Ubuntu" using "Wubi"